# Connect To IP Camera > Make 2nd Network Connection To Home Network > Stream To YouTube With Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, youtube, video-streaming

I'm properly stuck.

I own a Ordro HDV-Z20 video camera.  It has a WiFi option.  When I connect adhoc and issue the command **ifconfig** I get the following response:

```
rpiggott@rpiggott-Aspire-5742Z:~$ ifconfig
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 88:ae:1d:78:6c:09  
    UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
    RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
    Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
    inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
    RX packets:401 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:401 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
    RX bytes:28003 (28.0 KB)  TX bytes:28003 (28.0 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:ac:4c:71:e2:01  
    inet addr:192.168.1.33  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
    inet6 addr: fe80::604b:7981:40f3:426/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:100 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
    RX bytes:19380 (19.3 KB)  TX bytes:16810 (16.8 KB)
```

When I try these IP addresses a configuration page for the video camera isn't displayed:

- http://127.0.0.1/
- http://255.0.0.0/
- http://192.168.1.33/
- http://192.168.1.255/

I want to be able to stream my IP video camera to my YouTube channel.  I am wondering if there is a package I need to install in my Ubuntu 16.04 which will present me with the option of an IP camera (similar to my life of Printers)

Comment: An IP camera is supposed to be a standalone network device in the same network with its own unique IP address. Connecting *ad hoc* as you did is for configuration only. Accessing the camera's web server/page is done by typing the same IP as in the *ad hoc* WiFi connection. There you should select your router's AP and provide the password like any other device in order to connect it to the same home network.

Comment: @MichaelBay I do not receive a configuration page for all the ip addresses list with the command ** ifconfig **.  I've modified my question to reflect your advise.  What you say makes sense to me, similar to my wireless printer.   Please review revised question.

Comment: ifconfig lists the computers IP address. Not the cameras IP address. Furthermore, 127.0.0.1 is the loop back adress, and 255.0.0.0 is the netmask of the loopback adapter.

In short, there is zero reason to even expect it to respond to those IP's. Try 192.168.1.1 for instance - or read the manual for the camera.

I am not sure what you're trying to do, but you're doing it wrong...